# Prove that there is no permutation of the first n naturals satisfying a condition such that every sum of 4 consescutive terms is equal to 1 mod 2.

Tags: permutations, modular-arithmetic

> Given a set $\left ( 1, 2,3,...,n \right )$ where $n>5$ , I want to show that given all permutation $p$ $\left ( \sigma \left (  1\right ), \sigma\left (  2\right ),\sigma\left ( 3 \right ),...\sigma\left (  n\right ) \right )$,  there does not exist a permutation such that for $\forall$ k $\in \left  ( 1,2,3,...,n-3 \right )$
> the sum
> $\sum_{k}^{k+3} \sigma \left (  k\right ) = 1 (mod\: 2)$.

**What I Tried** :- For $n=5$ there are $12$ solutions that all share in common having all the odd numbers in the central $3$ positions, that's why $n>5$, but checking through all permutations up to $n=12$ found me no solutions, hence I believe that this can be generalized for $n>12$ but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you easily get $\sigma(1)\equiv \sigma (5)\equiv \sigma(9)\cdots \pmod 2$ and $\sigma(2)\equiv \sigma (6)\equiv \sigma(10)\cdots \pmod 2$ , and similarly starting with $\sigma (3), \sigma(4)$  And, since for large $n$, there are about as many even as odd numbers on the list, we must have that two of these are $0\pmod 2$ and two of them are $1 \pmod 2$, a contradiction.   Some case work is needed to get the bounds on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first $4$ entries have either $1$ or $3$ odd numbers, say $3$ for the moment. The $2$nd to $5$th entries only differ from the first by one entry, so it must also have $3$ odds. And similarly for every run of length $4$. But that too many odd numbers in the whole set.

Similarly, if all runs of $4$ entries have only one odd number, that’s too few odd numbers altogether.